# web service doesn't work with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, web-services

Community, I'm doing a web service in PHP where I need what brings information of a database in mysql.

What I don't understand if I pass all the code in one file (for example into client.php) this works fine, but here separated in two files doesn't work, in server.php not enter to while function where I create an array with all the info that mysql query brings.

Someone can help me?

server.php

```
<?php
//call library 
//require_once ('config.php');
require_once ('lib/nusoap.php'); 

$servidor = '?';
$user = '?';
$pass = '?';
$base = '?';

//using soap_server to create server object 
$server = new soap_server; 

//register a function that works on server 
$server->register('get_message'); 



// create the function 
function get_message($your_name) 
{ 
    if(!$your_name){ 
        return new soap_fault('Client','','Put Your Name!'); 
    } 


    $conexion = mysql_connect($servidor, $user,$pass);
    mysql_select_db($base, $conexion);
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM ensayos_santa_laura where ENS_FECHA_MUESTREO > '2015-01-01' ";
    $datos = mysql_query($consulta, $conexion);
    $numDatos = @mysql_num_rows($datos);
    $registro = array();

    $contador = 1;
    while($fetchrow = mysql_fetch_row($datos)){

            $registro[$contador]['WS_NUMERO_MUESTRA'] = $fetchrow['2'];
            $registro[$contador]['WS_FECHA_MUESTREO'] = $fetchrow['3'];
            $registro[$contador]['WS_NUMERO_CERTIFICADO'] = $fetchrow['4'];
            $registro[$contador]['WS_FECHA_ENSAYO'] = $fetchrow['5'];
            $registro[$contador]['WS_NUMERO_GUIA'] = $fetchrow['6'];
            $registro[$contador]['WS_EDAD'] = $fetchrow['7'];
            $registro[$contador]['WS_DENSIDAD'] = $fetchrow['8'];
            $registro[$contador]['WS_RESISTENCIA'] = $fetchrow['9'];
            $registro[$contador]['WS_RT'] = $fetchrow['10'];
            $registro[$contador]['WS_TIPO_HORMIGON'] = $fetchrow['11'];
            $registro[$contador]['WS_NUMERO_CONTROL'] = $fetchrow['12'];
            $registro[$contador]['WS_ASENTAMIENTO'] = $fetchrow['13'];
            $registro[$contador]['WS_LINK'] = $fetchrow['14'];
            $registro[$contador]['WS_ESTADO'] = $fetchrow['15'];
            $registro[$contador]['WS_TIPO_PROBETA'] = $fetchrow['16'];
            $registro[$contador]['WS_CODIGO_OBRA'] = $fetchrow['17'];
            $registro[$contador]['WS_UBICACION_HORMIGON'] = $fetchrow['18'];

            $contador++;

    }



    $cantidad = count($registro);





    if($registro){
        return $registro;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }


} 
// create HTTP listener 
$server->service(file_get_contents("php://input")); 
//$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
exit(); 
?>
```

client.php

```
<?php 
require_once ('config.php');
require_once ('lib/nusoap.php'); 
//Give it value at parameter 
$param = array( 'your_name' => 'Monotosh Roy'); 
//Create object that referer a web services 
$client = new nusoap_client('http://172.17.56.61/ws_santalaura/server.php'); 
//Call a function at server and send parameters too 
$response = $client->call('get_message',$param);



 //Process result 
if($client->fault) 
{ 
    echo "FAULT: <p>Code: (".$client->faultcode."</p>"; 
    echo "String: ".$client->faultstring; 
} 
else 
{ 


    $xml = new DOMDocument();

    $dateInfoElement = $xml->createElement("dateInformation");
    foreach ($response as $key => $value) {
        $xmlNode = $xml->createElement($key,$value);
        $dateInfoElement->appendChild($xmlNode);
    }
    $xml->appendChild($dateInfoElement);        
    $header = "Content-Type:text/xml";

    header($header);
    print $xml->saveXML();
    //echo var_dump($response); 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)

```
mysql_fetch_row — Get a result row as an enumerated array
```

Instead, try using [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php):

```
mysql_fetch_array — Fetch a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both
```

**NOTE:**

> Warning These extensions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed
>   in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be
>   used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more
>   information. Alternatives to this function include:
>   mysqli_fetch_array() PDOStatement::fetch()

Comment: Sorry, my explain was bad. The problem is what we have two files, client.php and server.php. In "client.php" is where we receive all the information and in "server.php" is where exist the query and while. If we put the query and while in "client.php" works, but if we have the info for separated, this doesn't work D:

Comment: mysql_fetch_row() is a subset of mysql_fetch_array(). It returns one record from the resultset and advances the internal record poiner to the next record. It is the same as calling mysql_fetch_array() with MYSQL_NUM as $result_type. See mysql_fetch_array() documentation on return values.

Comment: but is strange, if i put all the content (server.php and client.php) in one file works fine but if i separate that in two files doesn't work.

Comment: @EstebanVivanco pls update your question to show both versions of the code.